# Count 2 (or more) characters recursively in string; return in (x,y) format in Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, recursion, count

I have written a program that will count how many `' '` single spaces or `h` characters in a string you enter when you call the function:

```
def chars(s):
    if not s:
        return 0
    else:
        return (s[0] == 'h') + chars(s[1:])
```

When you call `chars('hello how are you here')`

You will get `3`.

Now, let's say I want to count the `e` along with the `h`. The `h` will return a `3` and the `e` should return a `4`. Output would be `(3,4)`.

I tried `def chars(s, j=0)`and set a counter but then realized, hold on, this has no connection to anything at this point deeming it pointless. I guess, how would I define what that second variable is? Because I only want 1 string as an input.

I am completely lost on how to include that second variable.

Also, just throwing it out there, would I follow the same rules as for 2 characters for more characters? Or would there be a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
def count(s):
    if not s:
        return (0, 0)
    else:
        next_count = count(s[1:])
        return ((s[0] == 'h') + next_count[0],
                (s[0] == 'e') + next_count[1])

count("hello how are you here") # => (3, 4)
```

The base case returns the tuple `(0, 0)` and the recursive step looks at both of the values of the next count and adds one to each if necessary.

If you want more than 2 characters, just make the tuples bigger (probably using loops).

Comment: That does it! Thank you very much! Ideally looping would be beneficial later on with more characters. Thanks again!